# Using the show route in react + rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm building out a simple quiz app with a rails api rendering the questions in json and react pulling them in. However I'm not very experienced with react and I'm having trouble working out how to go about getting one question at a time displayed on the screen as the display is the same going to localhost:3000 or localhost:3000/questions/1. Any advice on how to get it using the show method when appropriate instead of index for everything would be really appreciated.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/v1/questions.json')
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      this.setState({questions: response.data})
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `index` route should show all the questions

So:

```
def index
    questions = Question.all
    however_you_render_json(questions)
end
```

And your `show` route should take the id from the URL and show one questions from that

```
def show
    question = Question.find(params[:id])
    however_you_render_json(question)
end
```

in your `routes.rb` file you should have

`resources :users`

which which automatically create the required routes, you can run `bundle exec rake routes` in rails console to verify the URI patterns

On the React end, the requests should be: 
`axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/v1/questions/)` for index or `axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/v1/questions/1)` for show.

Comment: Thanks for you response, I have those parts of it in exactly as you've described and the routes are showing in rake routes as they should. For some reason it just won't transfer over into the react to use the show route, it seems to take the index for every address

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the calls to your Rails API?

Comment: I've added the request in and I see what you mean now, sorry. My request is always grabbing all questions, do I need a separate request to get the question by id?

Comment: Your `get` method seems to be grabbing a static json file from the server.  it should be `axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/v1/questions/)` for index or `axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/v1/questions/1)` for show.  Again, check the output of `rake routes` to determine the proper url

Comment: Right, ok, this is making a lot more sense :) Ok, so now I just need to work out how to do multiple views in react, not covered that at all, and use the request for the specific question I need. Awesome, thank you

Comment: Glad I could help! Please accept my answer if you feel it has sufficiently explained the solution.